# Why is Visual Studio (VB) not reading my SQL connection string properly?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio

I am writing a small windows tool to search a few SQL databases. I was able to connect and search the first database without issues but I keep getting the following login error when I try to search the second database (Database 2):

> 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>   Login failed for user '\azahir'

You will find that `<Domain>\azahir` is not even specified in my connection string or anywhere in my few lines of code.

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class Form1

Dim Conn As SqlConnection
Dim Conn2 As SqlConnection

Private Sub btSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btSearch.Click
    Conn = New SqlConnection("Data Source = <SERVER>;Initial Catalog=<DATABASE>;Integrated Security=SSPI;User ID = <Domain> \ axzahir;Password=<Password>;")
    Conn.Open()

    Dim cmd2 As SqlCommand = Conn.CreateCommand
    cmd2.CommandText = "select firstname, lastname
    from systemuserbase where firstname like" + "'%" + TxFirstName.Text + "%'" +
    " And lastname Like" + " '%" + TxLastname.Text + "%'"

    Dim dir As SqlDataReader = cmd2.ExecuteReader()
    If dir.HasRows Then

        Dim dtClient As New DataTable
        dtClient.Load(dir)
        dtOutput.DataSource = dtClient

    End If

    dir.Close()
    Conn.Close()
End Sub

....

Private Sub btnArgus_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnArgus.Click
    Conn2 = New SqlConnection("Data Source = <SERVER2>;Initial Catalog=<DATABASE 2>;Integrated Security=SSPI;User ID = <DOMAIN> \ axzahir;Password=<PASSWORD>;")
    Conn2.Open()

    Dim cmd3 As SqlCommand = Conn2.CreateCommand
    cmd3.CommandText = "select userID, Fullname
    from Users where FullName like" + "'%" + TxFirstName.Text + "%'" +
    " And Fullname Like" + " '%" + TxLastname.Text + "%'"

    Dim dir3 As SqlDataReader = cmd3.ExecuteReader()
    If dir3.HasRows Then

        Dim dtClient As New DataTable
        dtClient.Load(dir3)
        dtOutput.DataSource = dtClient


    End If

    dir3.Close()
    Conn2.Close()
End Sub
End Class
```

I have verified that my domain/username + password works for database 2. I am stumped as to why Visual Studio thinks my user is '\azahir' instead of the specified '\axzahir'. Any thoughts on how this can be fixed?

Thank you,
Asif

Comment: is this the actual code or have you anonymised ]the connection string

Comment: Don't know if this is a problem but at least it looks odd to me: Why are there spaces around the backslash in `<DOMAIN> \ axzahir`?

Comment: @SimonPrice Hey there, I have anonymised the connection string. I only left my username there.

Comment: @stickybit I have the space in my first connection string and it works. Removing the space works as well but I still get the same error for my second connection string unfortunately.

Comment: I think Integrate Security might be ignoring your user name/password.

Comment: Unrelated tips: `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader` are all `IDisposable` so should be in `using` blocks. And use parameters to remove the SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: @Xedni is right here, if you're using integrated Security, then the password and username values will be ignored; they arent required as the credentials have already been verified when the user logged in. As youre logged in as `azahir`, those are the credentials they will be used. You either need to add a login for `azahir` (and anyone else that would use the app), set up impersonation for a trusted connection, or use SQL Login Authentication.

Comment: If you look into SQL Server Management logs, does the failed login show up there ?

Comment: Thank you @Xedni Richardissmi, Larnu and everyone! I really appreciate this know-how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not how integrated security works. When using integrated security, there is no way to specify a specific username or the password. Instead, you get the user authorization for whatever user account runs your program. The entire connection string looks like this, with no specific user information:

> Data Source = <SERVER>;Initial Catalog=<DATABASE>;Integrated Security=SSPI;

If you want to specify a username and password, you *must* use SQL authentication. If you want to access the database as a specific domain account, you use integrated security, but *you have to run your app as that user*. There is no way to specify Active Directory credentials in a connection string and get that user's database access.

---

While I'm here, let me show you a better pattern for your database connection. (One that's not **crazy vulnerable to sql injection**! and will remember to close the connection even if an exception is thrown.)

Assuming a valid connection string:

```vb
Private ConnString As String = "connection string here"

Private Sub btSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btSearch.Click
    Dim SQL As String = _ 
      "SELECT firstname, lastname " & 
      "FROM systemuserbase " & 
      "WHERE firstname like '%' + @FirstName + '%' AND lastname Like '%' + @LastName + '%';"

    Using Conn As New SqlConnection(ConnString), _
          cmd As New SqlCommand(SQL, Conn)

        'Use actual database column types and lengths here
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20).Value = TxFirstName.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20).Value = TxLastName.Text

        Conn.Open()   
        Using dir As SqlDataReader = cmd2.ExecuteReader()
            dtOutput.DataSource = dir
            dir.Close()
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub

Private Sub btnArgus_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnArgus.Click
    Dim SQL As String = _ 
      "SELECT userID, Fullname " & 
      "FROM Users " &  
      "WHERE FullName like '%' + @FirstName + '%' AND Fullname Like '%' + @Lastname + '%';"

    'Note I can use the same variable names. 
    ' These are scoped to the method, not the class.
    ' Different scope, different variables, even though the names are the same
    Using Conn AS New SqlConnection(ConnString), _
          cmd As New SqlCommand(SQL, Conn)

        'Use actual database column types and lengths here
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20).Value = TxFirstName.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20).Value = TxLastName.Text

        Conn.Open()    
        Using dir As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            dtOutput.DataSource = dir 
            dir.Close()
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```